# passing multiple attributes of an entity in Hibernate ColumnTransformer

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a class consisting of multiple attributes

```
@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
@Attribute(keyword = "CUSTOMERLEDGER_FIRSTNAME", resolvedKeyword = "firstName", displayName = "First Name", length = 100)
@ColumnTransformer(read = "LOYLTY_DECRYPT(FIRST_NAME,CREATION_DATE)" , write = "LOYLTY_ENCRYPT(?,CREATION_DATE)")
private String firstName;

 @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
@Attribute(keyword = "CUSTOMERLEDGER_CREATIONDATE", resolvedKeyword = "creationDate", uiList = false, length = 20)
private Long creationDate;
```

I am passing CREATION_DATE while read and write function of `ColumnTransformer` annotation. At the execution of read, I can see the value of CREATION_DATE is passed to the function but at the call of write function, value of CREATION_DATE is not passed to function.

What can I do make this work ? As CREATION_DATE value is required by the function.

Comment: What do you mean by "value of CREATION_DATE is not passed"? The write transformer will be applied in insert/update statements for the `FIRST_NAME` column. If you need the updated value of `CREATION_DATE` to be used in the `LOYLTY_ENCRYPT` function, then you are out of luck. That doesn't work.